Chromium stops with "not secure" warning for internal network site
I run a webserver within my local LAN whose only purpose is to serve trivial, non-damaging services to my own network.  I use Raspbian Bookwork with Raspberry Pi (various versions) to access this (HTTP-only) site all the time.
Today I created a new Rpi / Bookworm server and started chrome to access this same server.  On this server, Chromium stops with a hard "site is not secure" message, and will not continue until a "button" is pressed ("Continue to site.").  This is bad news since the system is intended to be a clock, installed where nobody can easily reach it, with no keyboard or mouse installed.
All these servers work off of (copies of) a synchronized script; there are no flag differences and no intentional settings differences between the systems.
How can I tell Chromium to mind its own business, and stop protecting me from myself at my expense?  Or failing that, how can I proceed on to that site automatically?  :)
I have seen many sites addressing this by adding certificates to servers and on and on... and if I must, then I guess I will.  But I still hold hope that there is some sanity in the world and we can get past this with a switch and/or a setting.  Running chromium with the --help option, I get this (both encouraging and discouraging depending upon perspective) :
Other supported options are:
   chromium has hundreds of undocumented command-line flags that are added
   and removed at the whim of the developers.   Here,  we  document  rela-
   tively stable flags.

Does a way remain?  /etc/os-release (freshly installed and updated) :
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="12"
VERSION="12 (bookworm)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bookworm
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

Output of chromium --version:
Chromium 130.0.6723.116 built on Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)

URL of problem page:
http://velmicro.lovelady.com/clock/
# velmicro.lovelady.com is local to my network (192.168.*.* address)

Here is a screenshot of the problem:


you can get a list of chromium command-line flags by searching the internet for list of chromium command-line flags - however, I can't duplicate your issue. chromium does not behave as you claim on my systems

@Bravo There seems to be some doubt, so I updated the question with a screen shot.  As alluded to above, ("I have seen many sites addressing this...") my internet searching has not yet led me to a dorect answer.  That's the reason for my question here.

@Milliways call me ignorant.  What is a key set in this context, how will it help, and what must I do to implement it?  Interestingly, Google search for "chromium key set" seems to lead only to tools of which I have plenty at present.

ahh, incognito mode - I didn't try that, and can confirm that I now CAN duplicate the issue, details are important I guess

^^^ correction, nope, still works fine within local LAN, like it looks you are doing

@Milliways Yes, this is how I operate, but I don't see what that has to do with the question...I am simply tring to display a webpage on the system as full screen.  That's it.

You state that the URL of problem page - http://192.168.1.12/clock/ - but the error states that The connection is to velmicro.lovelady.com is not secure - does that look odd to you?

No, doesn't look odd.  velmicro.lovelady.com and 192.168.1.12 are the same system.  Sorry, I will update the question.  I was trying to make it clear that the address was internal, and not some external network thing.  We all know that 192.168.. are not reachable externally.  Bad attempt, though.

@Milliways - please read again.  I said that I will go the certificate route (which HTTPS will require) if I must, but this is about starting chrome while avoiding all of that.  Especially in light of the fact that so many other systems, purported running the same software with the same options, to not have this problem.   I want to understand why it doesn't work, not find a new way to do it.
